# Ajax call implementation with Controller interface in Spring

Tags: ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc

Currently I am on a legacy project of Spring mvc and annotations are not working on it.

I have to create an controller-action which will respond to an ajax call with JSON response.

I have created my controller by implementing [Controller](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html) interface.

I am able to implement a jsp page with this but unable to tweek it for ajax call.

Taking help from [link1](http://www.javablog.fr/javaspringjson-generate-json-withwithout-viewresolver-jsonview-with-json-lib-2-3-jdk15.html)  [link2](http://loianegroner.com/2010/02/spring-mvc-and-ajax-with-json/)  [link3](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/76361-spring-modelandview-containing-json)

Xml configuration in action-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="jsonResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver">
    <property name="order"><value>1</value></property>
</bean>
<bean name="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView">
    <property name="contentType">
        <value>text/html</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myOwnController" class="com.myapp.webapp.action.MyOwnController" />


<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <!-- list of inteceptor urls -->
        </list>
    </property>
        <property name="mappings">
        <props>
                    <prop key="/mytest">myOwnController</prop>
            <!-- mapping for other controller actions -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Controller class

```
package com.myapp.webapp.action
public class myOwnController implements org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller
{   
    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("success", "true");
        return new ModelAndView("jsonView", model);
    }
}
```

ajax call js method (in Prototype.js)

```
function myAjaxMethod(){
    new Ajax.Request('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsonView', {
          method:'get',
          onSuccess: function(transport) {
            var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
            alert("Success! \n\n" + response);
          },
          onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
        });
}
```

Also I am unable to understand that how the url in ajax call will get to know the this is the controller that should be called.Do I am missing any mapping?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution(not via Spring but via a dirty logic).

Warning : Never work on old Spring version project.

Solution : I rendered whole html response in ajax call, filter my data and parse into json.

action-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="myOwnController" class="com.myapp.webapp.action.MyOwnController" />

<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <!-- list of inteceptor urls -->
        </list>
    </property>
        <property name="mappings">
        <props>
                    <prop key="/mytest.html">myOwnController</prop>
            <!-- mapping for other controller actions -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Controller class

```
package com.myapp.webapp.action
public class myOwnController implement org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller
{   
    @Override
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
    {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("name", "davy jones");
        return new ModelAndView("mytest", model);
    }
}
```

Calling jsp Ajax call

```
function createFreshdeskUser(){
    new Ajax.Request('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/mytest.html', {
          method:'get',
          onSuccess: function(transport) {
            var divIdWordLength=16;
            var htmlData=transport.responseText;
            var startIndex=htmlData.indexOf("<div id=\"mydiv\">");
            var endHtmlData=htmlData.substring(startIndex+divIdWordLength , htmlData.length);
            var endIndex=endHtmlData.indexOf("</div>");
            var finalHtmlData=endHtmlData.substring(0,endIndex);
            var jsonObj=eval ("(" + finalHtmlData + ")");
            alert(jsonObj.name);
          },
          onFailure: function() { alert('Something went wrong...'); }
        });
}
```

mytest.jsp

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mydiv">{'name':'${name}'}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for, how to call a spring MVC controller from ajax function
This is all  done using annotation driven environment.

1) Need to make application annotation driven first and give your controller package there.

2) Add @RequestMapping to the fn that is going to be called from ajax fn, and provide maping URL to ajax fn 'url' attribute.

changes in p[om.xml

need to add, following library to convert and send response to ajax success in form of json.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

changes in spring conf file

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.beingjavaguys.controller" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "Content-type=application/json" })
    public @ResponseBody
    Response saveData(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        System.out.println("First Name: " + employee.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("Last Name: " + employee.getLastName());
        System.out.println("Email: " + employee.getEmail());
        System.out.println("Phone: " + employee.getPhone());

        return new Response("1", "Done");
    }
```

ajax function syntax

```
   function doAjaxPost() {
        var formData = JSON.stringify({
            firstName : $('#firstName').val(),
            lastName : $('#lastName').val(),
            email : $('#email').val(),
            phone : $('#phone').val()
        });

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "save",
            data : formData,
            contentType : 'application/json',
            success : function(data) {
                if (data.status == '1')
                    $('#status').html('Form data sent !');
                else
                    $('#status').html('Error in sending data !');
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this helps.
Use a button instead of submit to prevent page load on submit form and call ajax fn onClick.

Comment: Thanks for yr answer @neel4soft.Yr is correct but as my question states, no annotation like Requestmapping or requestBody is working for me due to very old version of spring.